# Caption of subfig

Tags: captions, subfloats

I use bellow code for make subfig in my text but figure caption are 2.2a, but I want 2.2(a). how change my code?
note: I don't want change all off code please correct my code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\section{subfig}
\subsection{problem}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{t.jpg}
          \caption{this fig}
           \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
            \label{f4}
    \end{subfigure}

     \vspace{0cm}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{t.jpg}
             \caption{this fig}
               \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
            \label{f5}
    \end{subfigure}

\caption{this fig}
   \label{f3}
\end{figure}
in fig.\ref{f5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Choose between *either* [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) *or* [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig), but not both. I'd suggest the former, since you're already using [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) (from the same author).

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want `1(b)` when you do `\ref{f5}`. For that change:

```
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
```

Your code modified

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{subfig}
\subsection{problem}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{t.jpg}
          \caption{this fig}
           \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
            \label{f4}
    \end{subfigure}

     \vspace{0cm}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{t.jpg}
             \caption{this fig}
               \setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
            \label{f5}
    \end{subfigure}

\caption{this fig}
   \label{f3}
\end{figure}
in \ref{f5}
\end{document}
```

[image]